# Gamma distribution - Poisson property

Tags: probability-theory, poisson-distribution, gamma-distribution

From my textbook after discussing the Gamma distribution and using the Poisson process postulates:

> It is left as an exercise to verify that

> $$
> \int_{\lambda w}^{\infty}\frac{z^{k-1}e^{-z}}{(k-1)!} \  dz=\sum_{x=0}^{k-1}\frac{(\lambda w)^xe^{-\lambda w}}{x!}
> $$

Here's what I have so far:

\begin{align}
\int_{\lambda w}^{\infty}\frac{z^{k-1}e^{-z}}{(k-1)!} \ dz&= \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{z^{k-1}e^{-z}}{(k-1)!} \ dz - \int_{0}^{\lambda w}\frac{z^{k-1}e^{-z}}{(k-1)!} \ dz \\
&= \frac{1}{(k-1)!} \left[\Gamma(k) - \int_0^{\lambda w}z^{k-1}e^{-z} \ dz \right]
\end{align}

I don't know if I set this up in my favor, but that right hand integral is getting nowhere with integration by parts. Am I missing something clever that I need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For ease of notation let $\mu = \lambda w$.

Note that integration by parts yields
$$\int_\mu^\infty z^{k-1} e^{-z} \, dz
= \mu^{k-1} e^{-\mu} + (k-1) \int_\mu^\infty z^{k-2} e^{-z} \, dz.$$
By a nearly identical argument, the integral on the right can be shown to be
$$\int_\mu^\infty z^{k-2} e^{-z} \, dz
= \mu^{k-2} e^{-\mu} + (k-2) \int_\mu^\infty z^{k-3} e^{-z} \, dz,$$
and you can continue integrating by parts on, until you end up with the base case $\int_\mu^\infty e^{-z} \, dz = e^{-\mu}$.

Thus,
$$\int_\mu^\infty z^{k-1} e^{-z} \, dz
= e^{-\mu} (\mu^{k-1}  + (k-1) \mu^{k-2}  + (k-1)(k-2) \mu^{k-3} + \cdots + (k-1)!)
= e^{-\mu} \sum_{m=0}^{k-1} \mu^m \frac{(k-1)!}{m!}.$$

Dividing both sides by $(k-1)!$ leads to the desired equality.

---

Approach using Poisson process with rate $\lambda$:

The waiting time until the $k$th arrival follows the gamma distribution whose PDF is the integrand on the left-hand side, so the left-hand side is **the probability that the $k$th arrival occurs after time $w$.**

The number of arrivals in the time interval $[0, w]$ follows the Poisson distribution with rate $\lambda w$, so the right-hand side is **the probability that $< k$ arrivals occur in the time interval $[0, w]$.**

These are the same.

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you!